# Searching for 3 posing buttons in Blender 2.8

Tags: interface, pose-mode

i use these little guys a lot in Blender, but i cannot find them in Blender 2.8,where did they go?

Important note,i am not looking for the shorcuts with the keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 4):

They can be found in the Pose Menu. 
[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you i found it.

Comment: @MaiSasaki since im currently learning about blenders interface i made a small addon that displays the copy/paste button the the header you can get it [here](https://github.com/TheRealSyler/Blender-Addon-Add_Copy_Buttons)

Comment: can you tell me how to install it? I tried "user prefer-addon-install from file" but it do not show on the addon list.

Comment: @MaiSasaki you need to unzip the file and when installing you need to go in to the unziped folder and choose the .py file or you can download my other [addon](https://gum.co/smenu) which will inculde the buttons (only in the next version 0010) the next version will come out later today or tomorrow

Comment: Nice, works perfectly!