# Copy data from transform panel

Tags: bones, transforms, panel

I've been trying to find out ways to copy and paste the transform (panel) data of one bone to another, but I can't seem to find anything about how to do this anywhere. I have roughly 40 bones I need to do this for, so it will get tedious trying to copy and paste the individual locations and rotations of the heads and tails of each bone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching for 3 posing buttons in Blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134607/searching-for-3-posing-buttons-in-blender-2-8)

Comment: Could you please elaborate.  Head and tail suggests edit mode. Possible dupe suggests pose mode. Copy transform of one bone to 40 others?  Are bones in same armature.